# OpenGL draw primitives

Tags: c++, opengl, draw, primitive, vertices

Please help.
I'm can not understand what method of draw primitives is better?

```
glBegin()
...
glEnd()
or
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
...
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

In many sources is sayd that `glEnableClientState/glDisableClientState` better than `glBegin/glEnd`, because count of function calls in first case smaller.
In real situation `glEnableClientState/glDisableClientState` and `glBegin/glEnd` used same size of memory, but `glEnableClientState/glDisableClientState` used more processor time.

In this example drawing just quads and `glEnableClientState/glDisableClientState` show worse result than `glBegin/glEnd`. Maybe i am misunderstand something?

Paths of code below:

```
struct stTexturedPoint
{
    float p[2];
    float t[2];
};
struct stTexturedQuad
{
    stTexturedPoint P[4];
};

struct stTexturedQuadArray
{
    vector<stTexturedQuad> TQ;
    unsigned int TextureId;
};

vector<stTexturedQuadArray> TQA;

void DrawTexturedQuad(stTexturedQuad TexturedQuad)
{
    glTexCoord2fv(TexturedQuad.P[0].t);
    glVertex2fv(TexturedQuad.P[0].p);
    glTexCoord2fv(TexturedQuad.P[1].t);
    glVertex2fv(TexturedQuad.P[1].p);
    glTexCoord2fv(TexturedQuad.P[2].t);
    glVertex2fv(TexturedQuad.P[2].p);
    glTexCoord2fv(TexturedQuad.P[3].t);
    glVertex2fv(TexturedQuad.P[3].p);
}

DrawAllMethod1()
{
    for(int j=0; j&lt;TQACount; j++) //vertex array count
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TQA[j].TextureId);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for(int k=0; k&lt;TQA[j].TQ.size(); k++)
        {
            DrawTexturedQuad(TQA[j].TQ[k]);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}

DrawAllMethod2()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    for(int j=0; j&lt;TQACount; j++)
    {
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float) * 4, &TQA[j].TQ[0].P[0].p[0]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float) * 4, &TQA[j].TQ[0].P[0].t[0]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TQA[j].TextureId);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, (TQA[j].TQ.size() &lt;&lt; 2), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, Indicies);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a lot of deprecated stuff ( since 2007!! ), i would advice to read a tutorial on modern OpenGL. As example: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: The performance gain is to do with state transfers and cost of data transfer to GPU. You can refer to many discussions on this subject, for ex, https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182731-Performance-problem-VBO-vs-Immediate-mode

Comment: Thank for links. Way that i use - really bad?

Comment: @FelixK. I read example with texture. Cant understand first parameter in function glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0); 0 - vertex, 1 - texture?

Comment: You can look up these parameters in the documentation: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml
The index is the attribute location inside the shader which can be retrieved by calling `glGetActiveAttribute` for all attributes and `glGetAttribLocation` for the specific you want to bind.

Comment: @FelixK. Understand. Will try.